# Gnome 3 on FreeBSD 9

Tags: freebsd, gnome3, gnome-shell

I recently installed FreeBSD 9-Release and I want to install Gnome 3 after having installed marcuscom ports. However after a long time, it stops with an error in `libgdata`.

How can I solve this problem to install Gnome Shell on FreeBSD 9?

Comment: Can you actually include the error message? That would probably help a lot

Answer (score 1):

Two ways: The first one is to debug it yourself.  The second one is to report a bug on the port site.  Gnome is fairly well supported by the FreeBSD team. Make sure you include as much information as possible in the bug report -- the error message sure would help!